# Java: dividing BigInteger by 3 / Base 3 representation

Tags: java, algorithm, math, biginteger, integer-division

I need a fast way to dividing a BigInteger (1000 bytes) through 3. Because shifting isnt working I have to use divideAndReminder(). Is there a better/faster option? I use this every often so mostlikly jit will optimize it.

```
public byte[] div3(BigInteger big) {
  final List<Byte> al = new ArrayList();
  final BigInteger three = BigInteger.valueOf(3);

  while(!big.equals(BigInteger.Zero)){
    final BigInteger[] bigg = big.divideAndReminder(three);
    al.add(bigg[1].byteValueExact());
    big = bigg[0];
  }
  return toByteArray(al);
}
```

Can this be faster done with shifting?

Comment: (It can be done using iterated shifts & adds/subtracts - useful for word operations and machines without a useful division. I don't see any carries over to multi-word/math.BigInteger. (That said, the Oracle runtime contains a `private exactDivideBy3()` for multiplication.))

Comment: not sure if faster, but have you tried `BigInteger.toString(3)`?

Comment: (@user85421: FWIW, Oracles `toString(radix)` uses `divideAndRemainder()`- in an implementation of Schönhage’s radix-conversion.)

Comment: (@greybeard it also uses a mutable `BigInteger` (not `public`), so it has at least one advantage)

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned division by 3 can be done as multiply by 0xAA...AA+1, shift right *n+1*, where *n* is the number of bits in the multiplier and *n* is a multiple of 8 (or 4).

To minimise cost, for a given dividend you want an *n* bit multiplier, where *n* = the length of the dividend, rounded up to multiple of 8.  I guess that's what the `private exactDivideBy3()` does.  [To construct the multiplier for a given dividend you could start with the 0xAA...AA for the largest dividend you need to cope with, then shift right and or in 1.  You could keep a table of these.]

You could, of course, round *n* to a multiple of 64, if you assume the BigInteger is cranking 64 bits at a time.

Answer (score 0):

While 1000 bytes wouldn't seem to justify going to extremes (Schönhage radix conversion), one approach would be to break the `BigInteger` into parts easily handled - 3^20 or 3^40 look candidates, and convert down to 3 from there.